# <img> in webview works on iOS emulator, fails on iOS device

Tags: nativescript

This is an issue that sounds like it's already been fixed, but even after upgrading to {N} 4.2.4 I find that I can't load a local image file within a webview on an iOS device. Here's some sample code...

main-page.xml:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" class="page">
    <Page.actionBar>
        <ActionBar title="My App" icon="" class="action-bar">
        </ActionBar>
    </Page.actionBar>
   <GridLayout>  
      <WebView src="{{ htmlsrc }}" />
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

main-view-model.js

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;

function createViewModel() {
  var viewModel = new Observable();

  let style = '<style>div.marker {background-color: gray; margin-right: 24px;} img.marker {margin: 5px 0px 0px 5px;} li {font-size: 18pt; margin-bottom: 8px;} </style>'
  let htmlpre = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>' + style + '</head><body>';
  let htmlpost = '</body></html>';

  viewModel.htmlsrc = htmlpre;
  viewModel.htmlsrc += '<p>This is an image: </p>'
  viewModel.htmlsrc += '<div class="marker"><img class="marker" src="./marker_r.png"></div>';
  viewModel.htmlsrc += htmlpost;

  return viewModel;
}

exports.createViewModel = createViewModel;
```

I've tried all kinds off variations on the img tag's src property, such as

```
"marker_r.png"
"./marker_r.png"
"~/marker_r.png"
```

I've also tried specifying the fully-qualified and encoded path, all to no avail.  I've seen [issue 4443](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4443) that seems to address the topic, as well as [stackoverflow.com/questions/44505825/nativescript-ios-webview-local-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505825/nativescript-ios-webview-local-files), but am still left wondering how to get this to work.

Comment: As mentioned in other thread you have linked, you should use absolute path of file instead of relative path.

Comment: @manoj - yes I tried that.  In fact, I tried all of these variations:

  let imgSrc = fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path + "/";
  let imgSrc = encodeURI(fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path) + "/";
  let imgSrc = "file://" + fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path + "/";
  let imgSrc = "file://" + encodeURI(fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path) + "/";

with the html: 

viewModel.htmlsrc += '<div class="marker"><img class="marker" src="' + imgSrc + 'marker_r.png"></div>';

And none of these work on an actual iOS device.

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the issue with Playground?

Comment: Yes - see https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=2Jslpt&v=7. (Note that I cannot add a local file to the playground, but it shows the code I used)

Answer (score 0):

Things seems changed after WKWebview, it seems to allow read access only when we specifically mention the base path. Unfortunately {N} implementation doesn't allow an option to set the base bath but here is a workaround you can try.

[Load local images into WebView](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=2Jslpt&v=8)

If you like to keep the data binding working, then you will have to override the WebView's prototype chain for iOS and modify this method [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/46705ee33278e8f9ec04b00ea592dd65ba855e74/tns-core-modules/ui/web-view/web-view.ios.ts#L134).

Comment: If anyone is interested in following up, there is a [Github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6377) Thanks @David.